# Why do I get the error 'Illegal offset type' in this code?

Tags: php, foreach

Why do I get the error 'Illegal offset type' in this code on the line `$errors[$field] .= '<div class="error"><p>' . $error . '</p></div>';`?

Code:

```
$errors = [];
foreach ($validation->errors() as $field)
{
   $errors[$field] = '';
   foreach ($field as $error) {
      $errors[$field] .= '<div class="error"><p>' . $error . '</p></div>';
   }
}
```

Validation:

```
private function addError($field, $error)
{
   $this->errors[$field][] = $error;
}

public function errors()
{
   return $this->errors;
}
```

Solution:

```
foreach ($validation->errors() as $key => $fieldErrors)
{
   $errors[$key] = '';
   foreach ($fieldErrors as $error) {
      $errors[$key] .= '<div class="error"><p>' . $error . '</p></div>';
   }
}
```

Comment: Because an array cannot be a key for an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach ($field as $error)
```

this line suggests that `$field` is an array.  You cannot use an array as the key to another array.

```
$errors[$field]  << won't work!
```

To fix, change your `addError` method to:

```
private function addError($field, $error)
{
   $this->errors[$field] .= $error; //I changed [$field][] to [$field]
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I got it working on the foreach, check the edited answer. I cannot change the line you suggested because I need to know wich field has errors, like `username` or `password`.

Comment: @William My suggestion won't hide the name of the field.  In both the original code and mine, the name of the field is just `$field`. If you got it working, all is well.

Comment: Wouldn't it overwrite the previous value if there is more than 1 on that field with your suggestion?

Comment: @William Ah yes it would. I assumed you have one error per field, or that you concatenate the errors from the same field in sentences. eg: `Password is too short. Password must include a number` (that's what my updated answer does).  If you need these to be kept separately, an array makes sense. This is a different issue you bring up I think. Because by either approach, you still know which field the error came from, so the problem wouldn't be that you need to know the name which field has errors.